# After a while cannot ssh to amazon aws ec2 machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I've read several similar questions, and checked my username is ubuntu as I'm running ubuntu instance, my pem key is 400 permissions and .ssh folder is .600

```
ssh  -i ~/.ssh/my-key.pem ubuntu@myserver -v
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myserver [myserver] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/my-key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/my-key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
```

I'm really lost here and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been long time since this question was made, but I just resolved the same problem.

First, the .ssh folder permissions must be 0700, no 600

```
$ chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

Second, the server was installed on an Amazon EC2 instance, using the company's domain `mycompany.cxx`, a Elastic Load Balancer and SSL configuration. For some reason, the name myserver.mycompany.cxx didn't work.

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-key.pem ubuntu@myserver.mycompany.cxx
```

I could solve it using the public DNS name from the EC2 configuration:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-key.pem ubuntu@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```